# What is Decryption algorithm for Cisco Type 7?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cisco, cisco-ios

I want the algorithm for cisco type 7 encryption and decryption. On searching, I found out that it uses Vigenere cipher encryption but it won't work. Please anybody help me out. If I found some small lead then also it will be good.

Thank You.

Comment: Right, according [Cisco Routers Password Types](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/article/cisco-routers-password-types), it is a Vigenere Cipher. Regarding "but it won't work" no information is given what is your actual (programming) problem or even question. If interested in the cipher itself, you may have a look into [Vigenere Cipher](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975023/vigenere-cipher), [Vigenère cipher implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033991/) or other [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vigenere).

Comment: I got the program. But it's too lengthy in JS to understand. "https://www.itblizz.in/2021/07/cisco-type-7-password-decoder.html". I have posted on my blog you can check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Decrypting a type 7 key is pretty straight forward if you have the hash value and access to a Cisco device

Create a key chain

```
config t
!
key-chain test
 key 1
 key-string 7 "put your hash here"
end
!
show key chain
```

Note- some of the newer code will not allow you to see the keys however this method usually works and can be used to see the clear-text version of a key.